# Get friends emails with facebook api

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

I read lots of question about this issue.

There is a way to get my friends emails, with Graph Api, FQL or something?

I really need to import my Fb contacts into my App. But it seems there is not possible. Even setting a friend's email as public, I can't get it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Friend emails are not available, and probably never will be, via the Facebook Graph API or FQL. If you look at the [documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/permissions/), it says "N/A" in the friend column for the email row.

Comment: Many thanks OffBySome,
So, how does Foursquare invite your friends then?

Comment: People associate their FB account and they log their ID.  Then they call /me/friends and see if they have any of those ids logged.

Comment: Another way is to periodically populate your Facebook User ID column by using graph search on email: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?method=GET&path=search%3Ftype%3Duser%26q%3Dzuck%40fb.com

Comment: @Chronos Facebook lets certain apps do it. However, that is a special access that you'd need to get via special connections. E.g. Xobni gets all of your friends emails imported into its iPhone app. This is because Xobni and Facebook have ties through Y Combinator.