# Facebook Android - Send file to friend

Tags: android, facebook

I am developing an Android app. I need to have user to generate a virtual gift and send to a Facebook friend in the app. The gift can be a zip file which my app can generate and consume. I am not developing any server side code. Is it possible to have the Facebook SDK to send a private message or something else to a selected friend?

If this is not possible, I am also thinking about other solutions:

Is it possible to send a private image with some other data embedded in the image file as meta data?

Or, is it possible to get the email of a Facebook user and send through email?

Comment: Finding user's email is an answered question. Please check the link below http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13205517/access-user-email-using-new-facebook-android-sdk

Comment: Acutally what I need is the email of a user's friend, which seems not possible: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7603684/get-friends-emails-with-facebook-api